# Is there a better HTML escaping and unescaping tool than CGI for Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, escaping

`CGI.escapeHTML` is pretty bad, but `CGI.unescapeHTML` is completely borked.  For example:

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.unescapeHTML('&#8230;')
# => "…"                    # correct - an ellipsis

CGI.unescapeHTML('&hellip;')
# => "&hellip;"             # should be "…"

CGI.unescapeHTML('&#162;')
# => "\242"                 # correct - a cent

CGI.unescapeHTML('&cent;')
# => "&cent;"               # should be "\242"

CGI.escapeHTML("…")
# => "…"                    # should be "&#8230;"
```

It appears that `unescapeHTML` knows about all of the numeric codes plus `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&quot;`.  And `escapeHTML` only knows about those last four -- it doesn't do any of the numeric codes.  I understand that escaping doesn't generally need to be as robust since HTML will allow the literal versions of most characters except the four that `CGI.escapeHTML` knows about.  But unescaping should really be better.

Is there a better tool out there, at least for unescaping?

Comment: It doesn't handle &mdash; either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The htmlentities gem should do the trick:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'htmlentities'

coder = HTMLEntities.new

coder.decode('&#8230;') # => "…"
coder.decode('&hellip;') # => "…"
coder.decode('&#162;') # => "¢"
coder.decode('&cent;') # => "¢"
coder.encode("…", :named) # => "&hellip;"
coder.encode("…", :decimal) # => "&#8230;"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'hpricot'

Hpricot('&#8230;', :xhtml_strict => true).to_plain_text
```

Though you might have to fiddle around with the character encoding.

Comment: Use the htmlentities gem rather than hpricot.