# Incompleteness of `CGI.unescapeHTML`

Tags: html, ruby, escaping, cgi

`CGI.unescapeHTML` seems to unescape characters that cannot be expressed literally in HTML, such as `"<"`, which is escaped in HTML as `"&lt;"`:

```
require "cgi"
CGI.unescapeHTML("&lt;") # => "<"
```

But when it comes to characters that can be either expressed literally or not, it does not seem to unescape it. For example, `"§"` can be expressed in HTML also as `"&sect;"`, and the latter is not unescaped by this method:

```
CGI.unescape("&sect;") # => "&sect;"
```

1. Is this a feature? Is there any way to completely unescape HTML strings including these characters?
2. I can find description about `CGI.escapeHTML`, `CGI.unescapeHTML` in RDoc for [Ruby 1.9.3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescapeHTML), but I cannot find it for the newest Ruby. What happended to them? Are they depricated, or was there any change around these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this question was almost a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378847/is-there-a-better-html-escaping-and-unescaping-tool-than-cgi-for-ruby/383561#383561), which has a good answer that refers to `htmlentities` gem.

Answer (score 2):

You will find the documentation for newer Ruby versions in `CGI::Util`. `CGI::Util` also defines a constant with special characters and their escaped values. That list is pretty short:

```
> CGI::Util::TABLE_FOR_ESCAPE_HTML__
{
    "'"  => "&#39;",
    "&"  => "&amp;",
    "\"" => "&quot;",
    "<"  => "&lt;",
    ">"  => "&gt;"
}
```

Looking into the implementation of `unescapeHTML` you will find some more replacements depending on the charset of the string:

```
# File lib/cgi/util.rb, line 43
def unescapeHTML(string)
  return string unless string.include? '&'
  enc = string.encoding
  if enc != Encoding::UTF_8 && [Encoding::UTF_16BE, Encoding::UTF_16LE, Encoding::UTF_32BE, Encoding::UTF_32LE].include?(enc)
    return string.gsub(Regexp.new('&(apos|amp|quot|gt|lt|#[0-9]+|#x[0-9A-Fa-f]+);'.encode(enc))) do
      case $1.encode(Encoding::US_ASCII)
      when 'apos'                then "'".encode(enc)
      when 'amp'                 then '&'.encode(enc)
      when 'quot'                then '"'.encode(enc)
      when 'gt'                  then '>'.encode(enc)
      when 'lt'                  then '<'.encode(enc)
      when /\A#0*(\d+)\z/        then $1.to_i.chr(enc)
      when /\A#x([0-9a-f]+)\z/i  then $1.hex.chr(enc)
      end
    end
  end
  asciicompat = Encoding.compatible?(string, "a")
  string.gsub(/&(apos|amp|quot|gt|lt|\#[0-9]+|\#[xX][0-9A-Fa-f]+);/) do
    match = $1.dup
    case match
    when 'apos'                then "'"
    when 'amp'                 then '&'
    when 'quot'                then '"'
    when 'gt'                  then '>'
    when 'lt'                  then '<'
    when /\A#0*(\d+)\z/
      n = $1.to_i
      if enc == Encoding::UTF_8 or
        enc == Encoding::ISO_8859_1 && n < 256 or
        asciicompat && n < 128
        n.chr(enc)
      else
        "&##{$1};"
      end
    when /\A#x([0-9a-f]+)\z/i
      n = $1.hex
      if enc == Encoding::UTF_8 or
        enc == Encoding::ISO_8859_1 && n < 256 or
        asciicompat && n < 128
        n.chr(enc)
      else
        "&#x#{$1};"
      end
    else
      "&#{match};"
    end
  end
end
```

So: Yes, it only unescapes a subset.